# Use VPN inside a VM from Host OS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, vpn

Host OS: Mac OS X 10.14.2

Guest OS: Ubuntu 18.10 running inside VirtualBox v5.2.22

VM is set up with a VPN connection and works fine. I can use Remmina (remote desktop app) from VM to log on to the development PC at my client's site (running inside their network).

How do I set up my host OS to use the VPN to connect to the PC directly?

I tried to follow a few posts but was not successful. I can ping my VM from my MacBook Pro. But, not sure what further needs to be done.

Edit: I tried to use native VPN client from OSX, but it does not work and does not show any errors. This is the reason that prompted me to look for alternatives (i.e. connecting to the VPN from VM)

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to connect your MacBook host to the VPN on your guest? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I'm not certain that it can be done (connect a host to the VPN connection that the guest creates).  It may be better to try more troubleshooting with the straightforward VPN connection, and try alternatives with that.